# Can't complete the mup setup in Meteor-Up

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I have been able to get past #mup setup. I get the following error;

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------


Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[212.1.213.20] - Installing Node.js
[212.1.213.20] â Installing Node.js: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Warning: Permanently added '212.1.213.20' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    stdin: is not a tty
    sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
    sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
    sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
    sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed TaskList: Setup (linux)
```

I've found a lot about the error stdin: is not a tty but none of them make much sense to me.

Comment: So what's your question?  Do you want the error explained?  Or the problem fixed?  Or what?

Comment: Problem fixed. Also a good place to raise an issue is on the mup github repo

Comment: I know what the error is but not how to get around it in this instance. Problem not fixed after re-installing the server and starting over.

Answer (score 1):

Open your /etc/sudoers file, find the line that says `Defaults requiretty`, and change it to `Defaults !requiretty`.

This will disable the tty requirement globally.